# Unable to find the path to the view.cshtml file in the Razor Class Library(The Razor Class Library is .dll)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm currently working on an demo application of `ASP.NET Core 2.1`. 
I try to use the new `RCL`(`Razor class Library`) in my ASP.NET Core MVC application.

I have 2 projects in my Solution

1. Project 1 : ASP.NET Core MVC application
2. Project 2 : Razor Class Library(MVC)

The structure of my Razor Class Library is very simple:

- Areas

  - MyFeature

    - Views

      - Shared

        - _Layout.cshtml

↓ This is the source code of `_ViewStart.cshtml` in the project 1 ( ASP.NET Core MVC application)

```
@{
     Layout = "/Areas/MyFeature/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Steps to reproduce the issue :

1. Build Razor Class Library(MVC)
2. within Project 1( ASP.NET CORE MVC application) , add reference to `.dll`, `view.dll` generated by step 1 , .
3. Excludes dependencies on Project 2 (`RCL`).
4. Within Visual Studio , unload the Project 2 (RCL).
5. Build Project 1 (ASP.NET CORE MVC application).
6. The results are shown below.

[image: result]

Why do such errors occur?

I've upload my Project file [on Google Drive (DownLoad Link)](http://bitly.kr/ZZQO)

I want to encrypt files in Razor Class Library(MVC) .

Please tell me if my method is wrong or the steps are wrong.

I'll be looking forward to reply.

Comment: change "/Areas/MyFeature/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml" to "~/Areas/MyFeature/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"

Comment: It seems that we cannot specify the `Layout` by class Type .  I can see there's a `MyApp.Namespace.Shared.Areas_MyFeature_Views_Shared__Layout` type complied in the `RazorLib2.Views.dll` . However , all documents I read are talking about set the layout by path string .

Comment: @alireza khosravi . Thank you. I change location → `Layout = "~/Areas/MyFeature/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";`  but i failed. this is result screenshot → [link](https://imgur.com/Q6oL7ac)

Comment: @itminus  thank you. I don't understand what you're saying. Please explain it easily.  T.T

Comment: @jwp In your code , you want to set the Layout of project1 as the layout defined in project 2 (RCL) . However , if you unload the project 2 , the path string is not valid any more . So I'm wondering whether there's a way to set the layout by specifying a class type .

Comment: @itminus . Thank you, I don't know how. only conjecture...