# Is there a way to encrypt Razor Class Library to .NET Core MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I depended on the translator.
Please excuse me.

- Razor Class Library = RCL
- .NET Core MVC application = CMA

I thinking of a solution to this.
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52732801/unable-to-find-the-path-to-the-view-cshtml-file-in-the-razor-class-librarythe-r?noredirect=1#comment92394322_52732801)

I Think again from the beginning.

My goal is to encrypt the View.cshtml files of RCL.

I did Googleing. And I couldn't find the answer.

plz help me..

Comment: Why would you ever want to encrypt this cshtml file itself??? Noone/nothing will be able to parse/work with/ it...

Comment: @kayess thank you. I Distribute project files to customers.
I Prevent the customer from modifying the _layout.cshtml.
Is it impossible to encrypt and load .cshtml?

Comment: @jwp for example If I was your customer and I got your lib, I am still able to modify the html that is rendered by your dll before showing serve to end-user. you may be able to prevent people to view your code but I can still do whatever I want with the code your dll rendered.

Comment: @AnirudhaGupta thank you. You said you could hide the code.
I want the customer to be unable to modify _layout.cshtml of RCL.
Is it possible to hide _layout.cshtml of RCL?
I want to hide the most important _layout.cshtml.

Comment: using reflection I can see private variable of class in C#, If asp.net mvc api expose the code of .cshtml file using a function your code can be seen. There is no benefit, please check mike's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you could encrypt a Razor Class Library, there would be no point. They are designed to be overridden.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio#override-views-partial-views-and-pages

> When a view, partial view, or Razor Page is found in both the web app and the Razor Class Library, the Razor markup (.cshtml file) in the web app takes precedence.

Comment: Thank you. I read attached link. And I have a question.
If RCL's file name is the same as WebApp1's file name, WebApp1 is applied first.
If the name is not the same, what happens?
I have to hide _layout.cshtml.
_layout.cshtml is the first to appear after execution, there is RenderBody(). And I will not let the customer modify _layout.cshtml.

Comment: If the name is not the same, it will not override the RCL version. You cannot stop the customer modifying the output of the Layout file. They can use client side code to modify it in the browser. Maybe you should start a new question about your actual problem, rather than asking about problems arising from your solution to your problem.

Comment: thank you.When referring to link [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio), I have a question.
1. Why do I split RCL and CMA?

Additional questions.
2. Exclude project RCL from CMA. Then build the RCL and refer to the RCL.dll generated in the CMA. Is this wrong? (This is the method used in my posts.)

3. last.. What would you do if you wanted to hide _layout.cshtml from customers? Is there any way?
I don't know how to solve it. Tell me a hint or a way.

Comment: 1. Because that's how its done. RCLs are designed to be referenced as packages. 2. That is the correct approach. 3. Why do you want to "hide" layout.cshtml? What exactly do you want to prevent the user from doing?

Comment: Clarifying my last question, what kind of modification are you trying to prevent? Hiding a brand logo? A copyright notice or something?

Comment: Thank you.
I have additional questions on 2.
It was not possible to get the path of view files contained in the .dll file. Why not?

3.Indicates the license, copyright, and logo on the _layout.cshtml.
This code can be modified and distributed at random if the customer erase it.

If this problem is resolved, we will also hide the login screen and related Model and Controller. (Plan)

In fact, number three is the most important. I've been looking for this for days.
I usually use ASP.Net Core and MVC Pattern.

Comment: The customer is not able to modify the actual Layout file included in the RCL. They can modify its output by overriding it or through client side script, or they can use a disassembler to reverse engineer your RCL and build their own.